# Marking a grid with x and other symbols in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to using tikz. I have the following grid:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\newcommand{\nvar}[2]{
    \newlength{#1}
    \setlength{#1}{#2}
}

\nvar{\dx}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % fill outside cells
    \fill [orange!40] (-1,-1) rectangle ( 3, 0); 
    \fill [orange!40] (-1, 2) rectangle ( 3, 3); 
    \fill [orange!40] (-1, 0) rectangle ( 0, 2); 
    \fill [orange!40] ( 2, 0) rectangle ( 3, 2); 
% pressure cells
\draw [semithick][help lines, step=\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3);
\draw [thin,dashed][help lines, step=.5*\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3); 
\draw [red,thick] ( 0, 0) rectangle ( 2, 2);
\draw [red,thick] (-1,-1) rectangle ( 3, 3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to annotate the edges of my grid the to generate a picture that looks like this in tikz:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\nvar}[2]{
    \newlength{#1}
    \setlength{#1}{#2}
}

\nvar{\dx}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [draw=red, thick, fill=orange!40, even odd rule,] (-1,-1) rectangle (3,3) (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw [semithick][help lines, step=\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3);
    \draw [thin,dashed][help lines, step=.5*\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
      \foreach \j in {.5, 1.5}
      {
        \node [green] at (\i,\j) {$\times$};
        \node [black!80] at (\j,\i) {$\otimes$};
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The initial command replaces the 4 rectangles and the drawing of the borders by using the `even odd rule` with two rectangles. (I just think this is a neat trick and recently discovered it works in tikz and not just metapost. ;) So I couldn't resist...)

To annotate, I use two loops over variables, nesting them and using each value for both an iteration over the `x` coordinate and an iteration over the `y` coordinate. Basically, tikz will run through these loops with all possible pairs of `\i`/`\j` which saves typing.

[image: Annotated diagram]

Answer (score 5):

Because why not ? :P

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\dx{1cm}\def\mylista{}\def\mylistb{}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
  \foreach \y in {.5,1.5}{
     \xdef\mylista{\mylista (\x,\y)}\xdef\mylistb{\mylistb (\y,\x)}
  }
}
\draw[thick,red,double distance between line centers=\dx,double=orange!40] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
\draw [semithick][help lines, step=\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3);
\draw [thin,dashed][help lines, step=.5*\dx] (-1,-1) grid ( 3, 3); 
\draw --plot [only marks,mark=otimes] coordinates \mylistb;
\draw --plot [only marks,mark=x,mark options={color=green}] coordinates \mylista;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! The marks now have the same line width as the rectangles. I was trying to do this drawing the cross by hand.

Comment: @Sigur Oooh, that's a good one. I wonder how to automate that. I better ask the wizards later about the glyph widths to match the characters with line width.

Comment: (+1) I like the `double distance...`.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the code below at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment (just before `\end{tikzpicture}`).

```
\foreach \a in {.5,1.5}{
 \foreach \b in {0,1,2}{
   \node at (\a,\b){$\otimes$};
   \node[green] at (\b,\a){$\times$};
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Huh. Never occurred to me to do the green second...

Comment: @cfr, do you see any advantage on that?

Comment: No. Sorry. It was a joke. I didn't see your answer before I posted mine and then realised it was basically identical except for the ordering. I should remember I have a twisted sense of humour. Also, I have left my answer because I also showed a way to make the other code more concise. But I'll delete if you wish since you posted first.

Comment: @cfr, no! Don't worry. You noticed about the even/odd rule. It was nice.